# Add view in admin panel with same design as others

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

I'm trying to create a documentation part in my admin panel, and for that I created a custom admin site. I've overriden the `get_app_list` and `get_urls` methods in order to display a new line in the navigation bar and the dashboard, and I created a view to which this line redirects :

```
class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):    
    def get_app_list(self, request):
        app_list = super().get_app_list(request)
        app_list += [
            {
                "name": "Documentation",
                "app_label": "my_test_app",
                "models": [
                    {
                        "name": "Scripts modification",
                        "object_name": "Scripts modification",
                        "admin_url": "/admin/documentation/modif/",
                        "view_only": True,
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
        return app_list
    
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            path('documentation/modif/', self.admin_view(self.modif)),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls
    
    def modif(self, request):
        context = {
            'title':"Documentation",
        }
        return render(request, "documentation/scripts_modification.html", context)
```

Everything works correctly and when clicking on the new line, I'm redirected to the new view I created. However, I want my view to have the same design as the rest of the admin panel, which I didn't how to do.

I extended `admin/base_site.html` but I only get the top of the page, and not the `view site  log out` panel nor the navigation sidebar :

[image]

I have no idea what I should change/configure in order to have the same display as the other admin pages. Shouldn't extending `base_site.html` display what I want ? There's something I didn't really understand here and I can't find what nor where to learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the reason why it wasn't working!

There are a lot of `if` clauses in `admin/base.html` (which is extended in `admin.base_site.html`) that check the values of several variables.

In order to display the top right panel, the variable `has_permissions` must be set to `True`, and to have the `view site` link, the `site_url` should be set to the url of the site.

Now, to display the navigation bar, `is_nav_sidebar_enabled` need to be set to `True` and `available_apps` must contains all the apps to display.

By adding all of that to the context of the template, everything is rendered correctly like on the rest of the admin panel.

And my code now looks like that :

```
class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):    
    def get_app_list(self, request):
        app_list = super().get_app_list(request)
        app_list += [
            {
                "name": "Documentation",
                "app_label": "documentation",
                "models": [
                    {
                        "name": "Scripts modification",
                        "object_name": "Scripts modification",
                        "admin_url": "/admin/documentation/modif/",
                        "view_only": True,
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
        return app_list
    
    
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            path('documentation/modif/', self.admin_view(self.modif)),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls
    

    def modif(self, request):
        context = {
            'title':"Documentation",
            'has_permission': True,
            'site_url': reverse('scripts:scripts'),
            'is_nav_sidebar_enabled': True,
            'available_apps': self.get_app_list(request),
        }
        return render(request, "documentation/scripts_modification.html", context)
```